# How to remove a row/column from a result set?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a result set and needed to nest some of the results which is working great, I would like to clean up some of the unwanted columns if possible.

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
tempjson = {}
salesofficejson = {}
for row in rows:
    tempjson['id'] = row['stateId']
    tempjson['name'] = row['statename']
    row['state'] = tempjson
```

then remove `stateId` and `statename` from rows:

```
row.remove['stateId']  //did not work
row['stateId'] = None  //did not work
row.drop(['stateId']) // did not work
```

Comment: `del row['stateId']` does not work?

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: del row['statId'] did work thanks, I knew it was simple... thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what `rows` actually is but try:

```
del row['stateId']
```

Here is a dummy example that might help:

```
In [41]: k = {'test': [5], 'test_2': [15]}

In [42]: k
Out[42]: {'test': [5], 'test_2': [15]}

In [43]: k = pd.DataFrame(k)

In [44]: k
Out[44]: 
   test  test_2
0     5      15

In [45]: del k['test']

In [46]: k
Out[46]: 
   test_2
0      15
```